# How to add a skspritenode to a random position that is ALWAYS on the screen

Tags: swift, random, position, skspritenode, arc4random

I have tried several things already to add the sprite on the scene randomly and they have all worked. The problem is half the time they are on the screen and half the time they are outside the screen.

Here is what I originally tried.

```
    func placeButtons() {

        let button1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button1")

        let PositionX1 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))
        let PositionY1 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.height))  

        button1.position.y = CGFloat(PositionY1)
        button1.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX1)

        self.addChild(button1)
}
```

Here is the last one I tried.

```
    func placeButtons() {
        let button1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button1")

        let sizeX = Int(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame))
        let sizeY = Int(CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
        var randomX = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % sizeX)
        var randomY = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % sizeY)

        button1.position = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY)
        self.addChild(button1)

}
```

I need the button guaranteed to always appear on screen.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you position your button randomly within `self.frame`, then sometimes only the start of the button will be visible.

The maximum width & height you should use is

```
self.view.bounds.size.width - button1.frame.width    
self.view.bounds.size.height - button1.frame.height
```

so if you already know the button dimensions you want, update your randomiser to this

```
    let PositionX1 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.bounds.size.width - myButtonWidth))
    let PositionY1 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.bounds.size.height - myButtonHeight))
```

There's a good tutorial on this - http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions

Comment: let button1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button1")
        button1.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
       
        let PositionX1 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width - button1.size.width))
        let PositionY1 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.height - button1.size.height))

        button1.position.y = CGFloat(PositionY1)
        button1.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX1)
            
        self.addChild(button1)

Comment: is this correct? Because this is still spawning buttons off screen and halfway on.

Comment: yea this is still spawning buttons off screen and halfway on.

Comment: I see the problem, I think - you need to use the bounds size, and not the frame - I will update the answer

Comment: this is odd, now it only spawns buttons on the very left edge of the screen

Comment: I have been able to replicate your problem - but only by changing the ScaleMode of the scene.  If you set `scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill` I think this should work.  Have a look at the Ray Wenderlich tutorial on this https://www.raywenderlich.com/119815/sprite-kit-swift-2-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: we are getting closer. now they are always on screen but only the bottom half of the screen.

Comment: well if I go landscape it adds them across the full screen but then I run into sometimes they are off screen